# Compare Variables Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a router with two different outputs into Expression Transformation for SETCOUNTVARIABLE($$COUNT1) and  SETCOUNTVARIABLE($$COUNT2). I need a way compare $$COUNT1 and $$COUNT2. If they are not equal than move on to another task, if they are equal than do another. Is this possible? If so can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could possibly join the two flows, then compare the variables? Can you tell us what is your actual requirement for the mapping?

Comment: The requirements are 1) Compare two counts of two data sets                2) If the counts don't match then send an email and stop the job              3) If the counts match then do another task.

Comment: What are the counts represent? Are they row count or something? Why are you using mapping variables?

Comment: Counts represent the total number of rows for data set1 and data set2. I am using mapping variables so that I can compare the two row counts of the two datasets. If I am incorrect on how to do this, or if there is a better way? please let me know!